How to Update Google Cloud Storage Transfer Job using Python API client?
I am trying to update the state to ENABLED of Google storage transfer job using the Python client storage_transfer_v1 and it raises this error: NotFound: 404 Requested entity was not found.
Note: The job exists because is being got with get_transfer_job method.
Here is the code:
client_transfer = storage_transfer_v1.StorageTransferServiceClient()

# Construct the job_name in the required format

# Get the existing transfer job
transfer_job = client_transfer.get_transfer_job(request=storage_transfer_v1.GetTransferJobRequest(
    job_name=transfer_job.name,
    project_id=transfer_job.project_id))

# Update the status
transfer_job.status = storage_transfer_v1.TransferJob.Status.ENABLED

# Define the fields to update
update_mask = FieldMask()
update_mask.paths.append("status")

# Create the request object for update
update_request = storage_transfer_v1.UpdateTransferJobRequest(
    job_name=transfer_job.name,
    transfer_job=transfer_job,
    update_transfer_job_field_mask=update_mask
)

# Update the transfer job
updated_job = client_transfer.update_transfer_job(request=update_request)


Please provide reproducible examples. You don't specify the PyPi library (assume: google-cloud-storage-transfer 1.12.0). You don't include the code where your "Construct the job_name". Your code shadows|duplicates transfer_job (i.e. transfer_job.name) in transfer_job which is confusing and omits the prior definition. Please include the stacktrace rather than a summary of the error. For these reasons, it's difficult to help.

Okay, I just tried this.
You're missing the project_id parameter in UpdateTransferJobRequest to uniquely identify the job.
You also need only specify the FieldMask field in the transfer_job to update that value (see either|or)
So...
requirements.txt:
google-cloud-storage-transfer==1.12.0

main.py:
import os

from google.cloud import storage_transfer_v1
from google.protobuf import field_mask_pb2

project_id = os.getenv("PROJECT")

name = "foo"
job_name = f"transferJobs/OPI{name}"

client_transfer = storage_transfer_v1.StorageTransferServiceClient()

# Create
request = storage_transfer_v1.CreateTransferJobRequest(
    transfer_job=storage_transfer_v1.TransferJob(
        name=job_name,
        description="Foo",
        project_id=project_id,
        transfer_spec=storage_transfer_v1.types.TransferSpec(
          posix_data_source=storage_transfer_v1.types.PosixFilesystem(
              root_directory=".",
          ),
          posix_data_sink=storage_transfer_v1.types.PosixFilesystem(
              root_directory=".",
          ),  
        ),
        status=storage_transfer_v1.types.TransferJob.Status.DISABLED,
    ),
)
transfer_job = client_transfer.create_transfer_job(request=request)


# Get (redundant)
request = storage_transfer_v1.GetTransferJobRequest(
    job_name=job_name,
    project_id=project_id
)
transfer_job = client_transfer.get_transfer_job(request=request)

# Update
# Either (requires above Get)
transfer_job.status = storage_transfer_v1.TransferJob.Status.ENABLED

# Or (no need to Get)
transfer_job = storage_transfer_v1.TransferJob(
     status=storage_transfer_v1.TransferJob.Status.ENABLED,
)

# Define the fields to update
update_mask = field_mask_pb2.FieldMask(
     paths=["status"],
)

# Update
request = storage_transfer_v1.UpdateTransferJobRequest(
    job_name=job_name,
    project_id=project_id,
    transfer_job=transfer_job,
    update_transfer_job_field_mask=update_mask
)
updated_job = client_transfer.update_transfer_job(request=request)

BILLING="..."
PROJECT="..."
ACCOUNT="..."

EMAIL=${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com

ROLE="roles/storagetransfer.admin"

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}

gcloud billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

gcloud services enable storagetransfer.googleapis.com \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL}

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=${ROLE}

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json

python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install --requirement requirements.txt 

python3 main.py


It is raising me this error:
InvalidArgument: 400 Cannot update project_id.
I have created the job to transfer from aws s3 to google following this doc
https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-transfers/agentless/s3
i created the job DISABLED

Are you able to try the example in my answer? The job is DISABLED and so should be ineffective but demonstrates the point.

I wanna wait until the job finished, when a create the job enabled it start automatically
